# c++ function cant write to object

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to c++ programming, and this is my first c++ program. Feel free to comment on any improvements i could make or improper use of techniques apart my questions, so that i can improve the rest of the code as well. 
The program is a simple routine which checks if to balls collide. If they collide the speed vectors of both balls get opposed.
The problem i have is that the function "checkcollision" doesnt seem to be able to write the updated speed to the testball object. I am able to compute the distance but i cant change/write to testball.xspeed. Do you know any reason for this?

My other question is: I wanted to introduce the position and speed values as vectors. Therefore i created a vector class. But i was not able to use variables of this type in the ball class.
How can i create an vector object and use this one in the ball class?

Thank you so much in advance!

```
class vector {
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    vector(float x_,float y_){
        x=x_;
        y=y_;
    }
};


class ball {
public:
  //  vector position;  // doesnt work
  //  vector speed;
    float x;
    float y;
    float xspeed;
    float yspeed;
    ball(float x_,float y_,float xspeed_,float yspeed_){
        x=x_;
        y=y_;
        xspeed=xspeed_;
        yspeed=yspeed_;
    }

};

void checkcollision(ball testball, ball testball2){
    float distance;
    distance=pow(pow(testball.x-testball2.x,2)+pow(testball.y-testball2.y,2),0.5);
    if (distance<0.1){
        testball.xspeed=-testball.xspeed;
        testball.yspeed=-testball.yspeed;
        testball2.xspeed=-testball2.xspeed;
        testball2.yspeed=-testball2.yspeed;
        }

    }

int main (){
      float time=0;
      float timestep=0.1;
      float runtime=20;
      int xmax=10;
      int ymax=15;

      ball testball(5,5,2,2); // positionx,y, speed x,y
      ball testball2(4,5,1,2);

      for( double i = 0; i <runtime; i = i + timestep )
      {
          time=time+timestep;

          checkcollision(testball,testball2);
          writeFile(testball.x,testball.y,testball2.x,testball2.y,count);

      }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Due to pass-by-value your function is only modifying a copy.

Comment: You must define a different constructor for your vector class (with no parameters) to define it as a class member as you would do here.

`vector(){}` for example.

Comment: When you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time. **Never add to code that doesn't work.** And when you ask for help with a problem, try to describe the problem clearly; "I was not able to use variables of this type" could mean half a dozen things.

Comment: Don't use `class vector`. `vector` is already used by the standard library. Use something else, such as `geometric_vector`, `gvector`, or `cartesian_vector`.

Comment: Thanks you for the help, it works well with the new definition of the constructor without parameters, may i ask why?
I will try to describe my problems more clearly next time, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your checkcollision function is working at the moment is it will make a copy of the ball objects that you pass in and then modify the copies. At the end of the function those copies go out of scope and are lost.

One way to achieve what you want is to pass the parameters by reference. The function signature would like this:

```
void checkcollision(ball& testball, ball& testball2)
```

This means that the objects received by the function are just references to the objects created in your main function.

There are a lot of different ways to achieve what you are trying to do. This is just one.

Comment: Thanks  a lot, i tried a similar thing, but got the position of the "&" wrong, now it works!

Comment: One more question, am i allowed to pass local variables from main to another function? Dont i need a return value from checkcollision to main?

What about the approach to allocate memory using 
ball * testball = new ball in main and pass the pointer to the function?
Thanks!